# How can one obtain an AWS session token on the AWS website?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can one obtain an AWS session token on the AWS website?

(I [know](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/405#issuecomment-130342371) how to do it through CLI, but sometimes getting it from the website could be handy)

Comment: [What questions about the web user interface of a cloud computing service are off-topic and what questions are on-topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5028/18147)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible.

Session tokens and their accompanying temporary key and secret are only available from Security Token Service (STS) via API calls that the console does not offer a way to access.

The only ways to obtain tokens and credentials are those [mentioned](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html) in the IAM User Guide -- CLI, Powershell, and SDKs, all of which call the STS API, which you can also call with third-party code.